# ERROR - Additional information: Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 0

Tags: sql, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, azure

Using Microsoft Visual Studio Community - deploying through Azure.

I have been stuck on this problem for 5 days. While trying to save user answers to a quiz, I KEEP getting this error. I have looked through so many other solutions to people asking the same thing and have not found any of them fixes my solution. This is the full error:

> An exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code
>   Additional information: Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 0.

I have looked and relooked at my connection string and code itself and have not found anything wrong.

Here is my code :

```
@using WebMatrix.Data;
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";

var Q1 = "";
var Q2 = "";
var Q3 = "";
var Q4 = "";
var Q5 = "";
var Q6 = "";
var Q7 = "";
var Q8 = "";
var Q9 = "";
var Q10 = "";
var weeknum = "";

if (IsPost)
{
    Q1 = Request.Form["Question1"];
    Q2 = Request.Form["Question2"];
    Q3 = Request.Form["Question3"];
    Q4 = Request.Form["Question4"];
    Q5 = Request.Form["Question5"];
    Q6 = Request.Form["Question6"];
    Q7 = Request.Form["Question7"];
    Q8 = Request.Form["Question8"];
    Q9 = Request.Form["Question9"];
    Q10 = Request.Form["Question10"];
    weeknum = "1";




    var db = Database.OpenConnectionString("PayForPlay", "System.Data.SqlClient");
    var insertCommand = "INSERT INTO  PayForPlay.WeeklyPredictions (WeekNumber, Question1, Question2, Question3, Question4, Question5, Question6, Question7, Question8, Question9, Question10) Values(@0, @1, @2, @3, @4, @5, @6, @7, @8, @9, @10) ";

    db.Execute(insertCommand, weeknum, Q1, Q2, Q3, Q4, Q5, Q6, Q7, Q8, Q9, Q10);
    Response.Redirect("~/Home/Submitted");
```

Here is my connection string:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name=“PayForPlay"
    providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
    connectionString="Data Source=tcp:memberships2016.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=PayForPlay;Integrated Security=False;User Id=annah@memberships2016;Password=Annie207!;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;MultipleActiveResultSets=True" />
    <!--<add name="PayForPlay" connectionString="Data Source=memberships2016.database.windows.net;Initial Catalog=PayForPlay;Integrated Security=False;User ID=annah;Password=*********;Connect Timeout=15;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False " /> -->
</connectionStrings>
```

The part of my connection string that is commented is another connection string I tried (following azure format) and it didn't work.

Comment: User ID=[LoginForDb]@[serverName]; ?

Comment: [Here's a good reference for Azure Connection String formats.](https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-azure/)

Comment: @Steve I just tried that and it still gave me the same error!!! arrgghhhhhh

Comment: Could you add the code of _Database.OpenConnectionString_ ?

Comment: @Steve what do you mean? OpenConnectionString is a method in the Database class of WebMatrix.Data... I wasn't aware I had to add code to that. I'm such a newbie with asp.net so please excuse my ignorance if I'm mistaken! Thank you so much for taking the time to help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[WebMatrix.Data.OpenConnectionString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg569301(v=vs.111).aspx), as far as I understands, wants a full connectionstring, not the key name of a connectionstring stored in the config file.

> The OpenConnectionString method differs from the Open method, which
>   uses the name of a connection string that is stored in the Web.config
>   file. You might use the OpenConnectionString method when a connection
>   string is programmatically generated or is provided by the user.

And this explains why that method cannot understand your 'PayForPlay' as a connectionstring. It expects to see a `"Data Source=memberships2016....."`

On the contrary, reading the documentation of the suggested [Open](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/webmatrix.data.database.open(v=vs.111).aspx) method you can see:

> The Open(String) method can connect to a database in two ways. The
>   Open(String) method first searches the Web application's App_Data
>   folder for a database file that matches the name that is passed
>   (without the file-name extension) to the method. **If no matching
>   database file is found, the method searches the application's
>   Web.config file for a connection string that matches name**.

So, it seems that your problem should be solved using the Open method with

```
var db = Database.Open("PayForPlay");
```

Comment: Thank you so much for all of your help Steve!! After I fixed that and changed PayForPlay.WeeklyPredictions just to WeeklyPredictions I got it working!!! I'm so happy !!